# What is the purpose of "self.each(callback, array)" in the jQuery source code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's `.each` function takes exactly one argument- a function. And yet, In this piece of jQuery code, we see the following:

```
if ( callback ) {
    self.each( callback, [ responseText, status, jqXHR ] );
}
```

Two args are being passed to `.each`. I'm assuming the values in brackets are params to the callback function, but I'm not clear on why this is possible and why someone would do this rather than calling the function directly? :

```
if ( callback ) {
    self.each( callback(responseText, status, jqXHR) );
}
```

Comment: lets say that `callback` returns a string.  `self.each( callback(responseText, status, jqXHR) );` would actually be the same as `var s = callback(responseText, status, jqXHR);self.each(s);` which is not going to work at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *"I'm not clear on why this is possible and why someone would do this..."*

They wouldn't. It's for internal use only: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L248-253

```
// Execute a callback for every element in the matched set.
// (You can seed the arguments with an array of args, but this is
// only used internally.)
each: function( callback, args ) {
    return jQuery.each( this, callback, args );
},
```

This behavior could change at any time.

---

To be clear, normally your callback to each gets two arguments:

- the `i` *(property name or index)* of the collection as the first
- the value of the item at `i` as the second

But sometimes internally they want to use the `each` iterator, but they have no need for those arguments, and instead they want to substitute their own.

That's what's happening. You [can see here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/core.js#L609-622) that if the internal `args` property has been given a value, they do a slightly different iteration of the collection passing the args that were given.

So they do:

```
callback.apply( object[ name ], args )
```

...instead of:

```
callback.call( object[ name ], name, object[ name ] )
```

...or slightly something different but effectively the same for an Array-like collection.

---

You can test it on your own:

```
 // normal usage
$('p').each(function( a, b, c ) {

     // will show the index, the element, and undefined for each "p" element
    console.log( a, b, c ); 

});

 // internal usage
$('p').each(function( a, b, c ) {

     // will show 1, 2, 3 once for every "p" element
    console.log( a, b, c );

}, [ 1, 2, 3 ] );
```

But again, this behavior isn't for public use, and could change without warning.

Comment: It's worth stressing that "internal use only" does not mean there's something to physically stop you using it; it means that it *shouldn't* be used and it's existence is undocumented, and nothing is stopping jQuery changing/ removing it's implementation in a later release, without giving any prior notice.

Answer (score 2):

[RightSaidFred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423068/417562) has answered part of this question – how the `each` call works. Here's *why* it's needed.

```
if ( callback ) {
    self.each( callback(responseText, status, jqXHR) );
}
```

That code won't work because it will call `callback` once, and then use the result of that as the argument of the `each` call. It is the approximate equivalent of

```
callback(responseText, status, jqXHR);
self.each ( true );
```

The next option is to do this with an anonymous function:

```
self.each (function() {
    callback(responseText, status, jqXHR);
});
```

This will work fine. *However* you have missing functionality. Your callback is run the correct number of times, but there is nothing to differentiate each iteration.  You might as well do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < self.length; i++) {
    callback(responseText, status, jqXHR);
}
```

By using `each` as the original code does, when `callback` is called, the relevant element in the array is used as the "context" – in practical terms, the value of `this` within the function. This means that the code can differ based on which element in the selection was passed.

Comment: +1 I didn't pay close attention to see the immediate invocation of the callback instead of the passing of it. Unless it returns a function, that clearly wouldn't work.

Comment: @lonesomeday- Thanks very much- Both you and RightSaid gave excellent answers, wish I could give you both cred.